# get_baseUrl RestSharp error

Tags: restsharp, dropnet

I just downloaded DropNet to try and use it. I am getting an exception when trying to do `new DropNetClient`:

```
Method not found: System.String RestSharp.RestClient.get_BaseUrl()
```

I searched this on Google and found that RestSharp may have introduced this error and it suggested to update to 105 for RestSharp but that did not solve things.

Is this a known error and how do I correct it from happening?

Comment: I have exactly the same error. Even after updating my dropnet nuget package from 1.9.6 to 1.9.12 I do not have seen this issue reported or fixed yet on github https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet

Comment: since 23 november 2014, baseurl is required https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/606

Comment: the official website of restsharp lists only version 103 http://restsharp.org/ as latest. I hope that they will update their nuget a.s.a.p. and dropnet might be updated too.

Comment: DropNet is now compatible with RestSharp 105.0.1 starting from version 1.9.20 https://www.nuget.org/packages/DropNet/

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a change in RestSharp that converted the BaseUrl property from a string to a URI.

DropNet needs to update their references & rebuild in order to support 105. This is the change that broke them...
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/b15ee7f60b695e0578b6def7a3e1279b62d6fccd

From https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases/tag/105.0:

> **New Features/Improvements**
>
> - Converted the BaseUrl to be a URI rather than a string (potential
>     breaking change)
> - Updated the SimpleJson package to the latest version
>     (potential breaking change)
> - Converted the use of tabs to spaces
> - Added
>     support for the DeserializeAs attribute on XML Added ability to
>     deserialize into structs
> - Added additional methods on RestRequest
>
>   - IRestRequest.AddJsonBody
>   - IRestRequest.AddXmlBody
>   - IRestRequest.AddQueryParameter
> - Added support for multi-part form
>     request to allow both a request body and files
>
> **Bug Fixes**
>
> Fixed potential Null Reference Exceptions on the parameters in
>   RestClient (ToString usage)

If you get Nuget package http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/104.5.0, then you should be okay...